# Unable to iterate over Azure ADGroupPaged object in python

Tags: python-3.x, azure

Experimenting with python3 to list AD groups but am blocked at an error when trying to loop through the ADPagedGroup class... packages used azure=4.0.0 and azure-graphrbac=0.61.0

I've tried with 2 versions of azure-graphrbac 0.40.0 as that'w what azure 4.0.0 requires, and with 0.61.0, errors either way.

`these_groups` is a type of [ADGroupPaged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/azure.graphrbac.models.ad_group_paged.adgrouppaged?view=azure-python), but there's no examples or doc that makes sense to me on microsoft's site.

In the code below, I've tried various permutations of iterating through the object `these_groups`

```
# ./adal_test1.py ## piece of shoe

from azure.common.credentials import get_azure_cli_credentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac.models import GroupCreateParameters, GroupAddMemberParameters   

# client_id, secret and tenant_id defined in list, but redacted here

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id=client_id,
    secret=secret,
    tenant=tenant_id
)

try:
    these_groups = graphrbac_client.groups.list()

except expression as identifier:
    print('Huh, why?')

finally:
    for a in vars(these_groups):
        print("DEBUG: VAR::",a)

    for b in these_groups:
    #also    these_groups.list:
    # "           "      .list():
    # "           "      .list():
    # "           "      ._get_next:
    # "           "      .current_page:   # NOTHING RETURNED
       print('DEBUG: B is::',b)           # <-- we NEVER make it here
       for c in vars(b):
            print('DEBUG: LOOP LIST::',c)
```

The result of `pip3 adal_test1.py`

```
VAR: _async_get_next
VAR: next_link
VAR: _current_page_iter_index
VAR: current_page
VAR: _derserializer
VAR: _get_next
VAR: _response
VAR: _raw_headers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adal_test1.py", line 50, in <module>
    for b in these_groups:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msrest/paging.py", line 143, in __next__
    self.advance_page()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msrest/paging.py", line 129, in advance_page
    self._response = self._get_next(self.next_link)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/graphrbac/operations/groups_operations.py", line 306, in internal_paging
```

Just want to reference each AD group returned, but can NOT figure out how to use the [Paged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msrest/msrest.paging.paged?view=azure-python) object.

sampling of failures

```
for b in these_groups._get_next:
     TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

```
for b in these_groups:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msrest/paging.py", line 143, in __next__
    self.advance_page()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msrest/paging.py", line 129, in advance_page
    self._response = self._get_next(self.next_link)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/graphrbac/operations/groups_operations.py", line 306, in internal_paging
    url = self._client.format_url(url, **path_format_arguments)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msrest/service_client.py", line 155, in format_url
    base = self.config.base_url.format(**kwargs).rstrip('/')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'format'
```

```
    for b in these_groups.list:
AttributeError: 'ADGroupPaged' object has no attribute 'list'
```

Interesting difference, though, with methods `current_page` and `next_link`, nothing is returned,

Comment: Please try this `for g in graphrbac_client.groups.list(): 
     print('DEBUG: LOOP LIST::',g.object_id)`

Comment: why dont you just do dir(b) and see what it offers? or set a breakpoint and examine the object carefully?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but looks more involved than a couple of loops over a method call.

Poked into the guts of the `azure-cli` ( [a la: azure-sdk_for-python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) ) to find that they use a recursive function called `internal_paging` with some deserialization to walk the `ADGroupPaged` object [See lines: 298-344](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/555a4e1d69326071d0aff64075523949ba813da6/azure-graphrbac/azure/graphrbac/operations/groups_operations.py#L298,L344)

I'm a novice @ python so this is all good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution to my question was pretty straight forward, just not obvious in any MS documentation or otherwise (that I could find)

Two changes:

1) **Mandatory**. For ActiveDirectory calls, the *ServicePrincipalCredentials* construct needs the resource parameter specifically set to `graph.windows.net`

e.g.

```
resource_adgraph = "https://graph.windows.net"
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id=client_id,
    secret=secret,
    tenant=tenant_id,
    resource=resource_adgraph
)

graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient( 
    credentials, 
    tenant_id
)
```

2) *Optional*. Import the `ADGroup` class

```
from azure.graphrbac.models import GroupCreateParameters, GroupAddMemberParameters, GetObjectsParameters, ADGroup
```

## New Output : with relevant names redacted

```
. . .
DEBUG: VAR:: _async_get_next
DEBUG: VAR:: next_link
DEBUG: VAR:: _current_page_iter_index
DEBUG: VAR:: current_page
DEBUG: VAR:: _derserializer
DEBUG: VAR:: _get_next
DEBUG: VAR:: _response
DEBUG: VAR:: _raw_headers
DEBUG: B is:: {'additional_properties': {'dirSyncEnabled': None, 'onPremisesDomainName': None, 'odata.type': 'Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group', 'onPremisesSamAccountName': None, 'provisioningErrors': [], 'proxyAddresses': [], 'description': None, 'onPremisesSecurityIdentifier': None, 'lastDirSyncTime': None, 'onPremisesNetBiosName': None}, 'object_id': '04b__VALUE_REDACTED__43e', 'deletion_timestamp': None, 'object_type': 'Group', 'display_name': '__VALUE_REDACTED__', 'mail_enabled': False, 'mail_nickname': '__VALUE_REDACTED__', 'security_enabled': True, 'mail': None}
RAW ADGraph object:  __GROUP__NAME__REDACTED__
DEBUG: LOOP LIST:: additional_properties
DEBUG: LOOP LIST:: object_id
DEBUG: LOOP LIST:: deletion_timestamp
DEBUG: LOOP LIST:: object_type
DEBUG: LOOP LIST:: display_name
DEBUG: LOOP LIST:: mail_enabled
DEBUG: LOOP LIST:: mail_nickname
DEBUG: LOOP LIST:: security_enabled
DEBUG: LOOP LIST:: mail
. . . [snip] . . .
```